# How do I generate floating time barchart in excel?

Tags: excel, date, graph, bar-chart, timeline

I wish to automate the visualisation process of my activity monitoring process.
To do so, I import a starting time, ending time and activity name of an activity, afterwards I distribute these over separate sheets.

And now I'd like to first manually build a graph that visualizes the data in the desired way, and that's where I run into trouble.

Data and graph nearly visualized:

[image]

[image: image2]

Obtaining the desired way entails 2 more small steps, the first and most important one, which I have troubles with is:

1. Visualising the difference between two plotted bars, on the actual location/height of the difference, in stead of two bars going up to the starting, and ending point of an activity. (practically inversing the area that is plotted with the area that is not plotted*)
2. Clustering the activities into 1 vertical bar consisting of several smaller bars floating in the right time, visualising the time of the activity. But that's something I'll look into after solving 1.

Ps. if you are interested in the actual .xlsm for your own use feel free to send me a pm.

*As seen I already tried to use just the actual duration of the activities with their respective starting time, but it only yielded 1 line of identical bars.

Comment: not exactly sure what you want with point 1, but how creating a column with the difference and either plotting that by itself or as a third bar for each data point?

Comment: Solved; the piece of information that did the trick: http://peltiertech.com/floating-bars-excel-charts/
The trick was to add a stacked bar chart with starting time and activity duration stacked on top of eachother, and then editing the lower bar to be invisible.
Furthermore, the clustering of different activities to 1 single bar will have to be done by adding all the activity times in a certain row, then adding the missing time inbetween those times and once again making the added time invisible, only showing the activitytime.

Comment: -Scott, thanks for your suggestion, I did that, as was shown in the picture, but the actual moment the activity took place would be unknown. 
Just plotting the one on top of the other was indeed the road to succes, but it required the format of the cells containing the difference to be switched to "general" in stead of in "minutes" or any other time format for the scales to show a readable result.

Comment: Yeah. Now that I saw the link you posted its clearer now what you were after. Appreciate the link as well, it's a good resource :)